# After Repopulating a DataGridView, the DialogBox is Auto Closing

Tags: vb.net, dialog

```
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles btnDelete.Click

    'Declare Variables
    Dim DeleteName As String
    Dim Question As String

    Dim intRow As Integer

    'Get the row number of the current selection
    intRow = dgvList.CurrentCell.RowIndex

    'Get the FieldName of the proposed deletion
    DeleteName = CStr(dgvList.Rows(intRow).Cells("LookUpName").Value)

    Question = "Are you sure you want to delete " & DeleteName &
        " from the list?"

    DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(Question, "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                   MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If DialogResult = DialogResult.No Then Exit Sub

    'Delete Record
    Delete_LookUpTable_Record(ToolDBName, TableName, FieldName,
            ShortName(FieldName) & "Value", DeleteName)


    dgvList.Rows.Clear()

    PopulateFieldList(ToolDBName, FieldName, TableName)

End Sub
```

After this code runs, the Dialog Box that the dgvList is contained in automatically closes.  I have buttons also of 'Add' and 'Edit' and the dialog box stays open after repopulating the dgvList.

```
Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles btnEdit.Click

    'Declare Variables

    Dim NewName As String
    Dim OldName As String
    Dim RowUsed As String
    Dim intRow As Integer

    Dim NameCheckPass As Boolean

    'Read the Used Column of Selected Rows
    intRow = dgvList.CurrentCell.RowIndex

    RowUsed = CStr(dgvList.Rows(intRow).Cells("Used").Value)

    If RowUsed = "True" Then

        DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("The value is used already.  Confirm that " &
             "you want to change the current text.", "Confirm",
                                       MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                                       MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

        If DialogResult = DialogResult.No Then Exit Sub

    End If

    OldName = CStr(dgvList.Rows(intRow).Cells("LookUpName").Value)

    Dim frmEdit As New frmNameInput
    frmEdit.Text = "Edit Look Up Value"
    frmEdit.lblName.Text = "Edit Look Up Value"
    frmEdit.btnAdd.Text = "Update"
    frmEdit.tbxName.Text = OldName

    frmEdit.ShowDialog()

    NewName = frmEdit.tbxName.Text

    If NewName = OldName Then Exit Sub

    Dim FieldSName = ShortName(FieldName)

    'Check to see if Name is Unique on the DB Table
    NameCheckPass = UniqueName(ToolDBName, TableName, FieldSName & "Value", NewName)

    If NameCheckPass = False Then

        MessageBox.Show("Name is not unique, please re-enter", "Not Unique",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

    End If

    'Update DB Table
    Update_LookUpTable_Record(ToolDBName, Create_TableName(FieldSName),
        FieldName, FieldSName & "Value", NewName, FieldSName & "Value", OldName)

    dgvList.Rows.Clear()

    PopulateFieldList(ToolDBName, FieldName, Create_TableName(FieldName))

End Sub
```

So this code works perfect, not sure why the btnDelete closes.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

Check btnDelete properties in the designer, if DialogResult is set to something else then 'None' then the Form it is on will close if said form is used as a Dialog and the button is pressed.

Comment: All 4 buttons on the form "DialogResult = None", any other ideas?  Thank You!